How to recursively check if a String starts and ends with another String in Java without equals()?
I need to write a method private static boolean textStartSeqEndSeq(String text, String sequence).
The method compares text and sequence, where sequence has to be at the start and at the end of text. So, it must be contained at least twice in text.
For example:
text "ABCDEFG" and sequence "AB" are only partly true, so return false.
text "AB123AB" and sequence "AB" would return true.
This would normally be easy, but here are the restrictions:

No helper methods, only one method and the main method.
No loops or arrays, only recursion.
Only use isEmpty(), length(), substring() and charAt().

I'm probably overthinking this because I have been stuck on this for a while now, but all I get is error after error. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, also I am a beginner, so for you this might seem obvious and you can help me. Here is the code I've got so far:
    private static boolean textStartSeqEndSeq(String text, String sequence) {
        // Base cases
        if (text.isEmpty() || sequence.isEmpty() || sequence.length() > text.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (sequence.length() * 2 > text.length()) {
            return false; // Not enough room for sequence at both start and end
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        boolean start = false, end = false;
        String case1 = text.substring(0, sequence.length() - 1);
        String case2 = text.substring(text.length() - sequence.length());

        // Check if `text` starts with `sequence` using recursion
        if (!start) {
            if (case1.charAt(i) != sequence.charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
            return textStartSeqEndSeq(text.substring(i + 1), sequence.substring(i + 1));

        }
        if (!end) {
            if (text.charAt(j) != sequence.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
            return textStartSeqEndSeq(text.substring( j + 1), sequence.substring(j + 1));
        }
        return start && end;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("AB123AB", "AB"));// Expected: true
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("ABBA", "AB"));// Expected: false
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("ottootto", "otto"));// Expected: true
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("Golden Yacht", "acht"));// Expected: false
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("blue whales are blue", "blue"));// Expected: true
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("", "A"));// Expected: false
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("A", ""));// Expected: false
        System.out.println(textStartSeqEndSeq("A B C D", " "));// Expected: false
    }
}

And here are the errors I'm getting, it stops processing before it reaches if (!end){}:
C:\Users\Administrator\.jdks\corretto-21.0.3-3\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrainsNew\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56733:C:\Program Files\JetBrainsNew\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Administrator\IdeaProjects\ProgrammersProgram\out\production\ProgrammersProgram Temp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:4832)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1555)
    at Temp.isStartAndEndSeq(Temp.java:29)
    at Temp.isStartAndEndSeq(Temp.java:32)
    at Temp.main(Temp.java:45)

Process finished with exit code 1


Why is isStartAndEndSeq("A", "") expected to be false? I would expect it to be true, because "A" starts and ends with the empty string.

Oh yeah right, I forgot to mention that the Strings cannot be empty. In that case they have to return false.

Ok, that goes against the philosophy of Java's String.startsWith method, in which "abc".startsWith("") == true. But if that's the requirement, so be it.

By the way, you don't need any local variables. Simplify your code by not using them. Note that both i and j are set to 0 and never changed. Also, note that substring can take a single argument, returning the remainder of the string starting at a given index, which means you don't have to bother doing arithmetic on the string length - so another simplification.

And to solve your problem, I would advise learning to use a debugger. Most good IDEs, such as IntelliJ IDEA, have good debuggers that allow you to step through your program one line at a time and examine the current values of arguments and variables.

All you need is a blank sheet of paper and a pen, then you draw an algorithm to traverse a tree. Or find an already existing implementation. Since you didn't explain what is your code is doing in steps, the help is impossible. A debugger won't help you still you don't understand why you need to call you method twice from the both ends.

I used up a few sheets, but my understanding of recursion apparently isn't that good yet. I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days and got desperate which is why i sought for help here. you're right, i should have done that  and pushed through, i'll do that next time. thank you

Using indexes won't help you in this situation, since you're not allowed to pass them to a utility method or to iterate over the strings.
What you could do is to make sure that the first character in the sequence string corresponds to the characters in the first and text.length() - sequence.length() position in text.
If these 2 conditions are met, you could advance with a recursive call and pass a substring of both text and sequence without their first character. Basically, at each recursive step you're reducing the portions of strings to confront, until there is only 1 character left in sequence.
private static boolean isStartAndEndSeq(String text, String sequence) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(text);
    Objects.requireNonNull(sequence);

    if (text.isEmpty() ||
            sequence.isEmpty() ||
            sequence.length() > text.length()){
        return false;
    }

    //make sure that the first character in sequence matches the first character in text
    return sequence.charAt(0) == text.charAt(0) &&
            //make sure that the first character in sequence matches the first character in the substring at the end of text
            sequence.charAt(0) == text.charAt(text.length() - sequence.length()) &&
            //if there is only 1 character left in sequence we're done, because that character is being confronted during the current call, otherwise we need to advance to the next subset of the two strings
            (sequence.length() == 1 || isStartAndEndSeq(text.substring(1), sequence.substring(1)));
}

Here is also a demo at OneCompiler with your expected output. In the demo, I've also added extra cases suggested in the comments. Thank you @user85421 and @k314159 for your comments.

("ABC123ABC", "ABC") (or similar odd length sequence) will eventually throw an IndexOutOfBounds

maybe just length <= 2 ? (instead of == 2)

You shouldn't have sequence.length * 2 > text.length() because "ABABA" begins and ends with "ABA" but is less than twice its length.

Oh wow i get it now. the main issue with my code was that i, like k314159 said, that i used local variables, because i didn't really understand how to progress the chars. This made me understand it, thank you! i'll try writing my own version of this, so i have a better learning effect and won't repeat these mistakes again, since this is the beginning of my recursion journey lol.

i wish i could upvote it, but i don't have enough rep yet

@Kaizen985 I'm glad I could help. Also, good thing re-writing your own version. That will definitely help you to proper grasp the concept.

You only need to check sequence.length > text.length() - no need for * 2 at all. The text "AB" starts and ends with the sequence "AB", so it should return true.

@Kaizen985 True. Thank you!

I wonder about "So, it must be contained at least twice in text." from the question (reason why I deleted my comment asking OP about ("AB", "AB"))

@user85421 yeah, that was the reason why I initially left that condition for the base cases. I was too focused on trying to convey the recursive logic.

Reading stack traces is an important skill. Consider yours:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:4832)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1555)
    at Temp.isStartAndEndSeq(Temp.java:29)
    at Temp.isStartAndEndSeq(Temp.java:32)
    at Temp.main(Temp.java:45)


Entries are ordered from most recent to least, and you should be able to see that the last bunch are all inside the Java standard library.  Those you can mostly ignore, except for the last, which tells you what standard library method your code invoked to provoke the exception.  And the following entry tells you exactly on which line of which source file that invocation occurs.  In this case, the exception message, at the top, fleshes out the picture pretty well:
At line 29 of your Temp.java, at recursion depth 2 in Temp.isStartAndEndSeq(), that method invokes chartAt(0) on a String that has length 0.  It looks like that is going to be one of the two charAt() invocations on this line:

            if (case1.charAt(i) != sequence.charAt(i)) {


You've previously verified that sequence is non-empty, so it must be case1 that is.  And that's possible because initializing it as

        String case1 = text.substring(0, sequence.length() - 1);


makes it shorter than sequence, which itself could be as short as length 1.
I don't really follow what you're trying to do with that.  Among other things, do note that each invocation of your method gets its own local variables, including i and j, and you do not modify those after initializing them, so it would be clearer, and equivalent, to replace them with constants. But it also appears that you are making case1 an initial substring of sequence, and then checking whether it is, in fact, an initial substring.  I can tell you without computing anything that yes, it is.
Suggested approach
Recursion solves a problem at least partially in terms of the solution to a smaller version of the same problem.  Since you cannot have any helper methods, the problem to solve using such an approach is exactly the problem given (not a sub-problem).  That is, does a given string both start and end with a specified substring.  A smaller version of the same problem would mean a smaller target string, a smaller test sequence, or both.
In considering how to structure such a solution recursively, it might help to think about how you might approach a simpler yet similar problem: the one where you have to check only for a subsequence match at the beginning of the target string.  This is more straightforward, for you can compare the first characters, and on a match, compare the two tails after the first character.  From there, adding a test for a match at the end, as well, is not that big a stretch.
Supposing that the head and tail sequences are not allowed to overlap (which your code seems already to assume), I would not separate testing the head substring and tail substring into separate cases.  The basic operation would instead be

Handle base cases, that

the test sequence is length 0 (result true (!))
the target string is shorter than twice the test sequence length (result false)


Check that the first character of the test sequence matches both at the beginning of the target string and at the appropriate position near the end of the target string. (Note: not matching the two string ends, unless the test sequence is only one character.)

If either position does not match then return false
If both match then recurse to test the next position of the sequence.  The arguments to the recursive call will be the target string with the two just-matched characters removed and the tail of the test sequence after the first (just matched) character.




Thanks so much for this detailed answer! Your explanation really helped me see where my logic went off-track. I thought that for zero-indexed arrays, the last element is at length - 1, and wanted to ensure I wasn't going out of bounds, but I see now it didn’t make sense with the way I was setting up case1 as a substring causing it to sometimes end up empty, so it led to the exception. I also really appreciate your breakdown on using recursion without helper methods. It makes way more sense now to handle the start and end checks directly and just recurse on the rest. Thanks again for your help!

I'll also practice debugging and reading errors now, this could've been solved by me paying more attention to them. I usually just "debug" with my eyes and change the code then rerun it, but i realize now that my skill level is too low for that to actually work.

That isn't debugging.  To be blunt, it is the "changing random things until it seems to work" approach.  For a complicated problems, it may never converge on a correct answer.

Here is a different version...
boolean isStartAndEndSeq( String text, String sequence ) {
   if( text == null || text.length() == 0 || sequence.length() == 0 )  return false;      
   if( sequence.length() == 0 ) return true;          
   if( text.charAt( 0 ) != sequence.charAt( 0 ) ||
           text.charAt( text.length() - 1 ) != sequence.charAt( sequence.length() - 1 ) ) return false;      
   return isStartAndEndSeq( text.substring( 1, text.length() ), sequence.substring( 1, sequence.length() ) );
}


From the comments.  "Oh yeah right, I forgot to mention that the Strings cannot be empty. In that case they have to return false"   That means your second line,  if( b.length() == 0 ) return true; would be wrong since in that case, b would be empty.

Thanks four your comment, I have already modified my answer.

Here is one approach.
record TestData(String getText, String getSequence) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TestData> testCases = List.of(
            new TestData(null, null),
            new TestData("oooo", "o"),
            new TestData("fooxxxxxfoo", "foo"),
            new TestData("fooxxxxxfo", "fo"),
            new TestData("fooxxxxxf", "f"),
            new TestData("fooxxxxxf", "f"),
            new TestData("fooxxxxxfo", "fo"),
            new TestData("foxxxxxf", ""),
            new TestData("", "f"),
            new TestData("", ""),
            new TestData("aboxxxxxab", "ab"),
            new TestData("abab", "ab"),
            new TestData("ffff", "fff"),
            new TestData("ffff", "ffff"),
            new TestData("aba", "ab"));

    for (TestData td : testCases) {
        System.out.printf("%-13s %-4s - %b%n", td.getText(), td.getSequence(), 
                isStartAndEndSeq(td.getText(), td.getSequence()));
    }
}

Prints
null          null - false
oooo          o    - true
fooxxxxxfoo   foo  - true
fooxxxxxfo    fo   - true
fooxxxxxf     f    - true
fooxxxxxf     f    - true
fooxxxxxfo    fo   - true
foxxxxxf           - false  // empty sequence
              f    - false  // empty text
                   - false  // empty both
aboxxxxxab    ab   - true
abab          ab   - true
ffff          fff  - true
ffff          ffff - true
aba           ab   - false

The Process

first, check for illegal parameters and if found, return false.
Then it's just a matter of checking the first character of the expected sequence against its expected locations in the text string.
if all is well, advance the to the next sequence character and text characters by the use of substring.
if the sequence string is empty, return true as all characters have been located in text.
otherwise, and do a recursive call with the modified text and sequence strings.


private private static boolean isStartAndEndSeq(String text, String sequence) {
        // fail fast cases
        if (text == null || sequence == null || text.isEmpty()
                || sequence.isEmpty() || text.length() < sequence.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        char seqCharUnderTest = sequence.charAt(0);
        char endingTextCharUnderTest = text
                .charAt(text.length() - sequence.length());

        if ( endingTextCharUnderTest != seqCharUnderTest 
                || text.charAt(0) != seqCharUnderTest) {
            return false;
        }
        sequence = sequence.substring(1);
        if (sequence.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return isStartAndEndSeq(text.substring(1), sequence);

    }
}

Notes

No where did you specify how to hand null strings.  I chose to return false.
Nor did you specify how to handle "text = "xxx" and sequence = "xx" or "xxx".   So I opted to return true since the text does indeed start and end with those sequences, even though some characters are "shared."

